# Include literal % percent sign in printf formatting string

Tags: php, printf, percentage

Here is my code:

```
<?php printf( __( '%.0f' ), $mini_deck->rating_per.'%' ); ?>
```

My problem is that the "rating_per" percentage sign (%) isn't showing after the percentage number on my website. What's wrong in my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're treating `%` as part of the "string" that you're printf()'ing

Pass the actual numeric value as the argument to printf(), and include the percentage sign in the "mask" (it needs to be escaped with another `%` character)

```
<?php printf( __( '%.0f%%' ), $mini_deck->rating_per ); ?>
```

Comment: Mark, thank you very much for this quick and efficient reply.